# Generating the pretty bit at the end of a URL

Tags: strings, regex, f#, url

I'm having a dip into F# and am attempting not to write it like it's C#.

One area that bothers me is using members of `System.String`. These often need to be chained together, but the only way to do so that I've seen so far is pretty much the same as C#.

For example, I've written a function to generate the pretty bit at the end of a URL (similar to SE):

```
module String =

    open System.Text.RegularExpressions

    ///Makes a string suitable for use as part of a URL: 
    ///Removes syntax, replaces spaces with dashes and lowers case, 
    ///then trims first word after 30 chars
    let prettify (x:string) =  

        let parsed = Regex.Replace(x.Trim(),"[^0-9a-zA-Z ]","").Replace(" ","-").ToLower()

        match String.length parsed with
            | m when m > 30 -> 
                match parsed.IndexOf("-",30-1) with
                    | p when p < 0 -> parsed
                    | p -> parsed.[..p]
            | _ -> parsed
```

Is there a way to refactor this to be "better F#"?  I'm particularly concerned about how to better handle the methods on `System.String` and `Regex.Replace`. (The match part is a little convoluted to handle the edge case of the last word being the one that takes it over 30 chars.)

Comment: I posted my latest iteration of this method. There have been a few, but all had the horrible String functions line.

Comment: IMHO before focusing on syntax/style you should focus on conceptual properties. For example, that function is partial and impure. Most likely you don't want that in such a function.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: Thanks for feeding back to me. Could you give me a quick pointer on both of those aspects please?

Comment: It's partial because it doesn't terminate for certain inputs (e.g. an exception).  It's impure because its output depends on a variable that is not part of its input (see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184574/why-is-today-an-example-of-an-impure-function ). As an exercise, try to figure out which inputs cause it to throw, and what is the "implicit" input variable that makes it impure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# does have [a `String` module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx), but it's almost empty. If you want to make string manipulations look more idiomatic, you'll have write functions that wrap `System.String` methods yourself (quick search didn't find anything existing):

```
let trim (input:string) =
    input.Trim()

let regexReplace (pattern:string) (replacement:string) (input:string) =
    Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement)

let replace (pattern:string) (replacement:string) (input:string) =
    input.Replace(pattern, replacement)

let toLower (input:string) =
    input.ToLower()

…

let parsed =
    x
    |> trim
    |> regexReplace "[^0-9a-zA-Z ]" ""
    |> replace " " "-"
    |> toLower
```

---

```
match String.length parsed with
    | m when m > 30 -> …
    | _ -> parsed
```

You don't need to try to differentiate from C# so hard. `if` would be more appropriate here:

```
if String.length parsed > 30 then …
else parsed
```

---

```
match parsed.IndexOf("-",30-1) with
    | p when p < 0 -> parsed
    | p -> parsed.[..p]
```

You can rewrite this to avoid having to reference `p` in both branches:

```
match parsed.IndexOf("-",30-1) with
    | p when p >= 0 -> parsed.[..p]
    | _ -> parsed
```

Also, use more descriptive names than `p`, like `index` or maybe `pos`.

---

Also, this code usually returns a string that's over 30 characters and ends with `-`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd found the string module and used `length` from it, but as you say, the other functions in it weren't very helpful here. I'd considered those wrappers, as an option if I need to do a lot of such manipulation.

Comment: btw, its intended to be >30 often as I want the last bit to be a full word. Will adjust for the trailing -